# Rust - why is my program performing very slowly - over 5 times slower than the same program written in JavaScript using Node

Tags: performance, rust

I have finished converting an application that I made in JavaScript to Rust for increased performance. I am learning to program, and all the application does is work out the multiplicative persistence of any number in a range. It multiplies all digits together to form a new number, then repeats until the number becomes less than 10.

My issue is, my program written in JavaScript is over 5 times faster than the same in Rust. I must be doing something wrong with converting Strings to ints somewhere, I even tried swapping i128 to i64 and it made little difference.

**If I run "cargo run --release" it is still slower!**

Please can somebody look through my code to work out if there is any part of it that is causing the issues? Thank you in advance :)

```
fn multiplicative_persistence(mut user_input: i128) -> i128 {
    let mut steps: i128 = 0;
    let mut numbers: Vec<i128> = Vec::new();
    while user_input > 10 {
        let string_number: String = user_input.to_string();
        let digits: Vec<&str> = string_number.split("").collect();
        let mut sum: i128 = 1;
        let digits_count = digits.len();

        for number in 1..digits_count - 1 {
            sum *= digits[number].parse::<i128>().unwrap();
        }

        numbers.push(sum);

        steps += 1;
        user_input = sum;
    }

    return steps;
}
```

```
fn main() {
    // let _user_input: i128 = 277777788888899;

    let mut highest_steps_count: i128 = 0;
    let mut highest_steps_number: i128 = 0;

    let start: i128 = 77551000000;
    let finish: i128 = 1000000000000000;

    for number in start..=finish {
        // println!("{}: {}", number, multiplicative_persistence(number));
        if multiplicative_persistence(number) > highest_steps_count {
            highest_steps_count = multiplicative_persistence(number);
            highest_steps_number = number;
        }
        if number % 1000000 == 0 {
            println!("Upto {} so far: {}", number, highest_steps_number);
        }
    }

    println!("Highest step count: {} at {}", highest_steps_number, highest_steps_count);
}
```

I do plan to use the numbers variable in the function but I have not learnt enough to know how to properly return it as an associative array.

Comment: While we may be able to spot perf bottleneck just from looking at the Rust code, to compare we need the JS code too.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman true, I should have included the JavaScript code also, apologies! I will remember for next time! Thanks for your comment though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the issue is that converting a number to a string, and then re-converting it again into a number is not that fast, and avoidable. You don't need this intermediate step:

```rust
fn step(mut x: i128) -> i128 {
  let mut result = 1;
  while x > 0 {
    result *= x % 10;
    x /= 10;
  }
  result
}

fn multiplicative_persistence(mut user_input: i128) -> i128 {
  let mut steps = 0;
  while user_input > 10 {
    user_input = step(user_input);
    steps += 1;
  }
  steps
}
```

**EDIT** Just out of curiosity, I'd like to know whether the bottleneck is really due to the string conversion or to the rest of the code that is somehow wasteful. Here is an example that does not call `.split("")`, does not re-allocate that intermediate vector, and only allocates once, not at each step, the string.

```rust
#![feature(fmt_internals)]

use std::fmt::{Formatter, Display};

fn multiplicative_persistence(user_input: i128) -> i128 {
    let mut steps = 0;
    let mut digits = user_input.to_string();
    while user_input > 10 {
        let product = digits
            .chars()
            .map(|x| x.to_digit(10).unwrap())
            .fold(1, |acc, i| acc*i);
        digits.clear();
        let mut formatter = Formatter::new(&mut digits);
        Display::fmt(&product, &mut formatter).unwrap();
        steps += 1;
    }
    steps
}
```

I have basically inlined the string conversion that would be performed by `.to_string()` in order to re-use the already-allocated buffer, instead of re-allocating one each iteration. You can try it out on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=59d98bf55eb661c25e9c5cfac0c0d493). Note that you need a nightly compiler because it makes use of an unstable feature.

Comment: Thank you so so much, the performance is much higher now!! I didn't think about doing it that way by keeping it as an integer, the more you know! :)

Comment: @figgyfarts I have an other version that does the string conversion, but without any other allocation. I'd be interested in knowing whether this is enough to make it outperform JS, or if it's really the string conversion that is costly.

Comment: I have been running them side-by-side, and lets just say the Rust version you proposed first blows it away! The JavaScript version running for over 5 days has got to around 270 trillion on my Raspberry Pi. The Rust version I set off yesterday got to 150 trillion within a few hours! I will try your new version when I get home :) thank you again!

Comment: just tried them both against each other, and unless my testing is super inaccurate, they don't seem too dissimilar!

Comment: Just tried the method without string conversion in C# and it is very fast!